# create a popup / dialog composite on eclipse startup

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, popup, app-startup

I want to display a popup on eclipse startup without clicking any button.

I have a plugin class which implements `org.eclipse.ui.IStartup` but from there i dont know how to create a popup which can be launched as soon as eclipse launches. Condition is popup should be shown without clicking anywhere, but just on the eclipse launch.